# como posso reduzir essa linha de código em javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Tenho um arquivo assim:

```
<html>
<script>
  var a = document.createElement('script');
  a.src = 'js/index.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].appendChild(a);
</script>
</html>
```

Tenho uma pasta chamada js, nessa pasta tenho 8 arquivos com a extensão .js. Esses arquivos possuem linhas de código bem parecidas e semelhantes...  Por isso fiz em ordem alfabética e também para facilitar a sua visualização de código e análise.

Comecei da letra "a" até a letra "g". Com exceção do último arquivo, cujo o nome coloquei: "index.js". Como pode ver logo abaixo:

a.js

```
var j = document.createAttribute("id"); 
j.value = "ty";
var k = document.getElementsByTagName("ty")[0]; 
k.setAttributeNode(j);
```

b.js

```
var h = document.createAttribute("id"); 
h.value = "rty";
var i = document.getElementsByTagName("rty")[0];
i.setAttributeNode(h);
```

c.js

```
var g = document.createAttribute("id"); 
g.value = "avs";
var h = document.getElementsByTagName("avs")[0];
h.setAttributeNode(g);
```

d.js

```
var a = document.createElement('avs');
document.write('<avs></avs>');
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].appendChild(a);
```

e.js

```
var c = document.createElement('ty');
document.write('<ty></ty>'); 
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].append(c);
```

f.js

```
var b = document.createElement('rty'); 
document.write('<rty></rty>'); 
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].appendChild(b);
```

g.js

```
var k = document.body;
k.parentNode.removeChild(k);
var l = document.head; 
l.parentNode.removeChild(l);
```

E por fim index.js:

```
var a = document.createElement('script'); 
a.src = 'js/d.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].appendChild(a);
var b = document.createElement('script'); 
b.src = 'js/e.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].appendChild(b);
var c = document.createElement('script'); 
c.src = 'js/f.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].appendChild(c);
var d = document.createElement('script'); 
d.src = 'js/c.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].appendChild(d);
var e = document.createElement('script'); 
e.src = 'js/b.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].appendChild(e);
var f = document.createElement('script'); 
f.src = 'js/a.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].appendChild(f);
var g = document.createElement('script'); 
g.src = 'js/g.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].appendChild(g);
var h = document.createElement("link"); 
h.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
h.setAttribute("src", "css/style.css"); 
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].appendChild(h);
```

Então... como posso reduzir essas linhas de código, para algo mais simples?

Comment: Primeiro, o que pretende obter com esses códigos?
Segundo, usar letras pra 'simplificar' o nome do script pode ser uma furada, melhor usar um nome mais fácil de identificar pra que serve aquele js

Comment: Criei usando o [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/nnOIfDjnVwPQBZqhdg59) o escopo do seu projeto, mas ainda não entendi o que deveria acontecer

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei exatamente o motivo desse código, só olhando ele não da pra entender o que você pretende fazer criando elementos no DOM que não existem no HTML em si.

Acho que antes de responder sua pergunta, gostaria que você explicasse qual o problema que você está tentando resolver pra depois te dar uma resposta ou uma ideia.

Algumas coisas que eu posso te adiantar são:

- Não crie arquivos e nem com nomes genéricos (a,b,c,etc..), fica quase impossível de decifrar o que o código significa. Exemplo:

  ```
  //Criando uma variável idade
  //má prática
  var i = 20;

  //boa prática
  var idade = 20;
  ```
- Document.write recarrega o DOM, e isso pode ser uma coisa muito ruim
- Quando você tem uma solução que vai se repetir várias vezes, a boa prática é criar uma função que recebe as variáveis e chama-la várias vezes.

Enfim, detalha melhor o que você quer fazer pra ser possível te ajudar com isso!